# Calculate $ E(X) $ where $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{y}e^{-(y+\frac{x}{y})}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

I am trying to solve the following probability problem:

> Please calculate $ E(X) $ where the joint density function of x and y is:
>
> $$f(x,y) =
>  \frac{1}{y}e^{-(y+\frac{x}{y})} \text{ for } x,y > 0$$

It is well known that the expected value of a continuous random variable is:

$$
E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty{xf_X(x)dx}
$$

That means that we have to find $f_X(x)$ first by doing:

$$
f_X(x)=\int_{0}^\infty{\frac{1}{y}e^{-(y+\frac{x}{y})}}dy
$$

Note: The zero lower bound is due to the given inequality $ y > 0$.

However, this integral turned out to be a handful (I tried substitution and integration by parts to no avail). Then, I tried this on WolframAlpha instead. However, it gave me an answer which I did not understand ([link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20from%200%20to%20infinity%201%2Fy%20*%20e%20%5E%20-(y%2Bx%2Fy)%20with%20respect%20to%20y)).

Am I even supposed to integrate this integral in the first place? I do not know much about the bessel function, which was present in the answer given by WolframAlpha. Furthermore, I am only undergoing an introductory probability course so it is not possible for the integral to be so complex (I was not taught bessel function anyway).

Could someone please advise me on how I could calculate the value of $E(X)$?

Comment: "That means that we have to find $f_X(x)$ first" Well, no. $$E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

Comment: @Did do you think his approach is generally wrong or for this particular case it is not a good choice? I am asking because I am unable to see anything wrong with the definitions he provided in second and third equations. I will be thankful if you could clarify why his approach is wrong (if it is). Thank you.

Comment: @FrankMoses Not wrong (and I do not see what it is that I wrote that could lead to believe it is), simply the method in my comment is always at least as easy to implement, and in some cases, such as the present one, it is spectacularly more so.

Comment: @Did Thank you for your help! I couldn't find this formula in my textbook. I'll add this formula to my notes.

Comment: Just a special case of the formula in your notes saying that, for every suitable $g$, $$E(g(X,Y))=\iint g(x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

Answer (score 1):

Make the change of variable $(x,y)\rightarrow (u,v)=(x/y,y)$ and obtain from $(x,y)=(uv,v)$ that $dxdy=v\,dudv$ and
$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}x\frac{1}{y}e^{-y-\frac{x}{y}}dx dy=\int_0^{\infty}ue^{-u}du\int_0^{\infty}ve^{-v}dv=1\times 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.
First find $f_Y(y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{y} e^{-(y+\frac{x}{y})} dx= e^{-y}$
Thus find expectation of $Y$ ,$E(Y)=\int_{0}^{\infty} ye^{-y} dy=1$
Now, find the distribution of $X|Y$ , which is $f_{Y|X}(y)=\frac{1}{y}e^{-\frac{x}{y}}$.Thus $X|Y \sim \text{Exponential}(y)$,with mean $y$.

Now, use law of conditional expectation,
$E(X)=E(E(X|Y))=E(Y)=1$